# How do I add an expandable box of extra information to a table row that is created in an Angular repeat statement?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a table within an angular app that looks like this:

```
<table id="visible_table" class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <tr class="info">
        ...
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in environment_service_packages | filter:isEnvironmentCorrect | orderBy:'service'">
        ...
    </tr>
</table>
```

I was wanting to make each table row clickable to where extra information would be displayed below that line's service. I have all the extra information already stored within the model. I can't seem to get the formatting of the extra data to work, however.

My original idea was to put an extra `div` at the end of the second `tr` tag so that it would be included within the repeat. I was able to get this information to appear, but each service's data appeared below the table rather than below the table row as expected.

I also tried doing a line break and doing a `td` that spanned across the entire table, but the `br` didn't end up changing the page's layout whatsoever.

I was considering turning each row into a simple `div` and removing the table structure altogether, but I wanted to check with SO to see if there was a better way first.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried ng-repeat-start \ end? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `<tbody>` to iterate over your `<tr>` elements:

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.environment_service_packages = 
    [
      {name: 'obj1', info: {text: 'some extra info for obj1', show: true}},
      {name: 'obj2', info: {text: 'some extra info for obj2', show: false}},
    ];
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app>
  <table ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <tr class="info">
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody ng-repeat="x in environment_service_packages">
      <tr ng-click="x.info.show = !x.info.show">
        <td> {{ x.name }}
      </tr>
      <tr ng-show="x.info.show">
        <td>
          {{ x.info.text }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: I never knew the `tbody` tag existed. Thanks for the information. Enjoy your bounty!

Comment: @LeePresswood also worth looking at the `<thead>` element!

Answer (score 1):

Just for your information: you can use [ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to accomplish this (but in this particular case, `tbody` suits your needs better):

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.environment_service_packages = 
    [
      {name: 'obj1', info: {text: 'some extra info for obj1', show: true}},
      {name: 'obj2', info: {text: 'some extra info for obj2', show: false}},
    ];
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app>
  <table ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <tr class="info">
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="x in environment_service_packages" ng-click="x.info.show = !x.info.show">
        <td> {{ x.name }}
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end ng-show="x.info.show">
       <td>
          {{ x.info.text }}
       </td>
     </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Example of usage `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` with header/footer

```
<header ng-repeat-start="item in items">
  Header {{ item }}
</header>
<div class="body">
  Body {{ item }}
</div>
<footer ng-repeat-end>
  Footer {{ item }}
</footer>
```